# Des trous de compréhension

Tags: oral

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre certains mots dans [cette vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V42kLjyDyUI) - pouvez-vous m'aider ?

À 19 secondes : *Quand on est hiver, il y a le blé, ___ (pangues ?), de l'orge*

46 secondes : *Tout ___ (un bout, en vue?) de diversité exceptionnelle*

2m45 : *ils sont formés sur (le tape, l'étape ?)*

Merci d'avance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La personne qui parle ne s'exprime pas dans un *bon français*, il ne faut donc pas se fier aux constructions grammaticales des phrases, même si la majorité sont correctes.

- À 19 secondes :

> Quand on est l'hiver, il y a le blé tendre, de l'orge

Merci à [Laure](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/358/laure) pour la confirmation du *blé tendre*.

Aussi, le début de la phrase n'est pas correct. Il faut dire :

> Quand on est **en** hiver

Une tournure tolérée (mais pas très jolie) :

> Quand **c'est** l'hiver

- À 46 secondes :

> Toute cette **bio-diversité**, c'est exceptionnel

- À 2min55 :

> Les gens ils sont formés **sur le tas**

«être formé sur le tas» est une expression qui veut dire qu'on apprend avec l’expérience, sans formation. On nous a demandé de faire un travail qu'on a jamais fait, personne ne nous dit comment faire, et au fil des jours, on apprend tout seul...

Comment: Le [blé tendre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bl%C3%A9_tendre) est l'espèce de blé la plus courante, celle avec laquelle on fait le pain. Appelé aussi froment.